# Incorrect Oozie dependencies when trying to install Cloudera Manager 5

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, cloudera, oozie, cloudera-manager

I'm trying to install the newest version of the Cloudera manager on my Hadoop cluster (Ubuntu 14.04), [following these steps](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_ig_install_path_b.html?scroll=cmig_topic_6_6#concept_p5r_lsx_34_unique_1). I moved Ubuntu Trusty Cloudera Manager list file to the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory, not realizing someone else had already moved the Ubuntu Precise list there as well. I ran through as much of the installation as possible and am now getting some weird dependency errors with Oozie:

```
% sudo apt-get install cloudera-manager-daemons
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cloudera-manager-daemons is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 oozie : Depends: oozie-client (= 3.1.3+155-1.cdh4.0.1.p0.1~precise-cdh4.0.1) but 4.1.0+cdh5.6.0+235-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.108~trusty-cdh5.6.0 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I list the Oozie packages installed I get:

```
% dpkg --list | grep "oozie"                                          
ii  oozie                               3.1.3+155-1.cdh4.0.1.p0.1~precise-cdh4.0.1            all          A workflow and coordinator sytem for Hadoop jobs.
ii  oozie-client                        4.1.0+cdh5.6.0+235-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.108~trusty-cdh5.6.0  all          Client for Oozie Workflow Engine
```

So `oozie` is using the Precise installation and `oozie-client` is using the Trusty one. I can't remove either of them (`purge` gives similar results):

```
% sudo apt-get  remove oozie-client                                 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 oozie : Depends: oozie-client (= 3.1.3+155-1.cdh4.0.1.p0.1~precise-cdh4.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I try to continue with the Cloudera installation I keep getting weird Oozie dependency errors. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a typo in one of the older sources.list files. Once this was replaced I was able to run apt-get update which then gave a different error.  Looked like it was trying to stop the oozie service and hitting a syntax error. Running service oozie stop gave the same error. Then went into the initscript /etc/init.d/oozie and took out the line which was giving the syntax error. Finally I was able to run apt-get update, uninstall conflicting oozie versions and reinstall Trusty versions.